# Can I Help Web Browsers Figure Out "Words" On My Pages?

Tags: html, css, browser

My question is about what web browsers consider words. The context of this question, is selecting text to be copied off of a web page. Not text in any kind of input, just straight content.

I actually have two very closely related question. The first is a bit of a bug that only affects WebKit browsers. On all browsers, double clicking a word will automatically select a word, without having to drag the cursor over the word. If you double click & drag, let lets you select text whole words at a time. It makes selecting words or sentences very easy. But here is the bug: In the following jsfiddle, if you use the double-click-and-drag text selection technique (again, only in WebKit), once you get to the 3rd pair of characters in the PREFIX column, the selection will automatically jump to include the first word in the COMPANY column.

The second question on the matter is more of a usability enhancement than a bug fix, however if it is possible, this would likely solve the previous bug.

So ignoring the bug, all web browsers treat colons as word-spacers. So the string "00:00:00" is treated, when it comes to word detection during selecting text, as "00 00 00". Is there a way I can help the browser determine what is a word and what is not? I do not want to change the actual content. However, that content is already in it's very own DIV element. If I could use CSS to somehow give a hint to the browser that that DIV contains one single word, that would make selecting much easier, while bypassing the original bug entirely.

The fiddle showing the problem: http://jsfiddle.net/yphb3s6o/1/

```
<section>
    <h2>Search Results</h2>
    <div id="mac_addr_results">
        <ul>
            <li><div>PREFIX</div><div>COMPANY</div>
            <li><div>40:f2:e9</div><div>Ibm</div>
            <li><div>a8:97:dc</div><div>Ibm</div>
            <li><div>98:be:94</div><div>Ibm</div>
            <li><div>34:40:b5</div><div>Ibm</div>
            <li><div>00:60:94</div><div>Ibm Corp</div>
            <li><div>08:00:5a</div><div>Ibm Corp</div>
            <li><div>08:17:f4</div><div>Ibm Corp</div>
            <li><div>10:00:5a</div><div>Ibm Corp</div>
            <li><div>00:02:55</div><div>Ibm Corp</div>
            <li><div>5c:f3:fc</div><div>Ibm Corp</div>
            <li><div>6c:ae:8b</div><div>Ibm Corporation</div>
            <li><div>74:99:75</div><div>Ibm Corporation</div>
            <li><div>e4:1f:13</div><div>Ibm Corp</div>
            <li><div>00:50:76</div><div>Ibm Corp</div>
            <li><div>00:25:03</div><div>Ibm Corp</div>
        </ul>
    </div>
</section>

body
    {
    background: #000000;
    color: #cccccc;
    }

#mac_addr_results
    {
    text-align: center;
    }

#mac_addr_results li > div
    {
    display: inline-block;
    width: 20%;
    }

#mac_addr_results li:nth-child(even)
    {
    background-color: #404040;
    border-radius: 3px;
    }
```

Seems rather pointless to include the raw code in this post, rather than linking to the jsfiddle which is interactive, but the site is forcing me to include the code in addition to the link. You need to actually view the fiddle and select the text in the "Result" pane to see these issues.

This is a lot of words for such a subtle problem, but I'd really love to get this behaving just right. Thanks.

Comment: Why aren't you using a table?

Comment: Have you considered Javascript to select-on-click?

Comment: @peehaa It's a pretty simple list. I suppose I could use a table. It might solve the odd WebKit bug, but the "make browsers treat this full string as a word" issue will remain.

Comment: @Joeri Hendrickx I looked into. The code is complicated and hard to make work. Plus I'd rather use a more elegant solution, if there is one.